# Why Using sha or likewise key in file or Image Urls?

Tags: url, web-development, security, url-encoding

As I'm new and do not have much insight about security what I have found while scraping websites using scrapy and such tools is that most of the websites like google while naming there image or other files have a long string of characters attached to them in their urls.Like a url of image from google will have a structure like - lh3.googlecontent.com/b/img/svwjhhjwhbwJNShvxwnkjbwjbxwhbxjHBhwbxjhwbx.png

Does it make it safe from getting crawled in bulk by using tools like wget etc because I have never found a problem crawling them or getting them downloaded.

Comment: Sorry but this question is off-topic because it is not about a website you operate. Also, security-related questions are best asked on the [Security Stack](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks.. I believe security stack had a similar one..so that helped.